# Utf8, Swedish characters, Doctrine, Mysql and Json serialization

Tags: php, mysql, json, utf-8, doctrine-orm

I have an application where I am trying out Doctrine2. I have a database configured with type InnoDB and collation utf8_unicode_ci.I then have a simple table with two columns: id(integer) and name(string).

I use phpmyadmin to enter a row into the table and then I use the following code to read the information from the database:

```
$serializer = JMS\Serializer\SerializerBuilder::create()->build();
$county = $entityManager->find('County', 1);
$jsonContent = $serializer->serialize($county, 'json');
```

The serializer I use is from http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer.

My entity-file for County looks like this:

```
    <?php
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

// src/County.php
/** @ORM\Entity **/
class County
{
    /** @ORM\Id @ORM\Column(type="integer") **/
    protected $id;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="string") * */
    protected $name;


    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}
```

When I try to run this on a row that has no swedish characters everything works, but if I enter a swedish character 'ä' through Phpmyadmin and try to read that row I get the following exception:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Your
>   data could not be encoded because it contains invalid UTF8
>   characters.' in
>   C:\wamp\www\doctrine\vendor\jms\serializer\src\JMS\Serializer\JsonSerializationVisitor.php
>   on line 36

Any hints on what I am doing wrong? I think this should work.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I added charset to the connection object and then it works.

```
$conn = array(
'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
'dbname' => 'doctrine',
'user' => 'doctrine',
'password' => 'doctrine',
'host' => 'localhost',
'charset' => 'UTF8'
);
```